# code cripto equivalent in php

Tags: javascript, php, hash

cripto frontapp response, how convert code for PHP?

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const apiSecret = 'YOUR_API_SECRET';

function validateFrontSignature(data, signature) {
    var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', apiSecret)
          .update(JSON.stringify(data))
          .digest('base64'); 
    return hash === signature;
}
```

Comment: use PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php (google is your friend)

Comment: hash_hmac("sha1"
                      , json_encode($dados)
                      , "53707069dc0fb92b6b12d704f16ee286"// API_SECRET
                       );

Comment: not working https://frontapp.com/integrations/webhooks